# Failed to install SQL Server

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, software-installation, sql

When I try to download SQL Sever following [the procedure in this blog](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2017/04/26/installing-microsoft-sql-server-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/) using the terminal on Ubuntu 16.04, 
I get this:

```
roqaia@roqaia-Inspiron-3558:~$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password far raqaia: The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install curl 


[1]+  Stopped             curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
roqaia@roqaia-Inspiron-3558:~$ url https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
[sudo] passward far raqaia: No command 'url' found, did you mean: 
 Command 'erl' from package 'erlang-base' (main)
 Command 'erl' from package 'erlang-base-hipe' (universe)
 Command 'zurl' from package 'zurl' (universe)
 Command 'ur' from package 'libur-perl' (universe)
 Command 'ul' from package 'bsdmainutils' (main)
 Command 'curl' from package 'curl' (main)
 Command 'uil' from package 'uil' (universe)
url: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't add code and output as Image/Screenshot but as text (formatted as code). This makes reading (and answering) your question more likely

Answer (score 0):

Please read the output you got:

> The programm 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   `sudo apt install curl`

just run

```
sudo apt update
```

to update the available packages list and than run

```
sudo apt install curl
```

as suggested to install `curl`.

Comment: Thank you derHugo but  It is give the same result  :                                           roqaia@roqaia-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt install curl
[sudo] password for roqaia: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 139 kB of archives.
After this operation, 338 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149)]

Comment: How is this the same result? It is saying that it is installing `curl`. Are you stuck at the `0%`? In this case make sure you are connected to the internet, dns-name-resolving works correctly (`ping google.com`) and that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is configured correctly